# Paypal Payment Data Transfer

Tags: asp.net, paypal, sandbox

I am new to paypal and I just have a simple question.  I am using an ASP.NET page to make a payment to paypal.  I have a sandbox account. My buyers account is decreasing, my facilitators account balance is increasing the sandbox transactions are successful. Now I need a way to tell my application that the transaction was successful so I can update a database.

My question is this, have Payment Data Transfer (PDT) been replaced by webhooks?  Should have a service and configure an endpoint to listen for the webhook from paypal.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the REST API, then yes you should use [Webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-webhooks-overview/).  If you are using the Classic APIs, then you should use [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/).

Comment: Thanks, I have set up an IPN listner to take care of the back end processing.